# JavaScript - Find Hashtags in Text and Return With Link

Tags: javascript, html, regex, web

I'm trying to take my text and convert that hashtags to links and different colors than the normal text, but I have no idea how to go about it. I know it has something to do with regex, but I can't seem to get it down. Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't work at all:

```
function hashtag(text) {
var repl = text.replace(/(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig, '$1<a style = "color: #35ab52">$2</a>');
return(repl);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: can you put together an example with data maybe on plunkr

Comment: `text.replace(/(#[^\s]*)/g, '<a style = "color: #35ab52">$1</a>');`

Comment: Not working :/ Nothing happens

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple function that replace all `#string` in a text with `<a href="#">#string</a>` :

```
function hashtag(text){
    var repl = text.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<a href="#">#$1</a>');
    return repl;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: Use Javascript Regex function to filter out the strings starting with hash symbols and hyperlink

Comment: Awesome. Thanks c:

Comment: Can please someone give me the regular expression for the @username.allow so that I can do the same for the mentioned usernames.